# Dynamically insert DOM when pageshow event trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

In my jQuery mobile application need to insert the DOM's when the pageshow event is called i try the whole day but not get success.

First insert some fields in `document.ready`, after that need to insert some other fields when the pageshow event is triggered.

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uouk35u1/16/)  what i tried

```
$(document).on("pageshow", "#a", function () {
    var a = $("#aDivMoreOptions").append("<h1>Hell</h1>");
});
```

**Note*:** strictly need to insert on the pageshow event only, not page create events, because when insert in pagecreate event after refresh all DOMS are gone.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks for your reply. where i repeat the id?.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you are saying about "c" right...after "c" having some texts

Comment: Actually - that's my mistake. I just noticed you're appending the `a` to the `id`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it is in the <div> html first line itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of document.ready, insert the panel on pageinit:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#a", function(){ $("#a").append(...) });
```

Then the panel will be there when pageshow is handled.

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/uouk35u1/17/)**

Comment: Thanks .one more "DivMoreOptions" is collapsible one so the <label> is inside collapsible but it is displayed outside

Comment: @Aravin, you need to append it to the collapsible content div: var a = $("#aDivMoreOptions .ui-collapsible-content").append("<h1>Hell</h1>"); Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/uouk35u1/19/

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling  `$("#a").trigger("pagecreate");` and listening `on("pageshow", "#a")`.
Just put a `$("#a").trigger("pageshow")` below the other trigger.

Like that:

```
$("#a").trigger("pagecreate");
$("#a").trigger("pageshow");
```